# How can I perform a task on an activity in Android without having to open that activity or when away from that activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity in Android from where I want to send email to a predefined email ID automatically at a particular point in time when I am either on other activities in the application or not on the application itself. How can I do that?

I am using broadcast receiver like this - code below

```
private void startMinuteUpdated() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        minuteUpdateReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                //perform a certain task like send email at a particular time

            }
        };
        registerReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startMinuteUpdated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        startMinuteUpdated();
        unregisterReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: try broadcast receivers you might find them usefull

Comment: I am using broadcast receiver when I am on the activity, however, how do I use it when I am not on the activity or the application is not running?

Comment: I want to check the timestamp every minute and send an email if it hits a certain time.

Comment: @BilalRammal I have updated the question with the current implementation of Broadcast receiver. How can I make use of it when I am not on the activity/application?

Comment: try using manifest declared broadcast receivers , but note that many receivers are not working anymore in higher apis so check out static broadcast receivers and find if your needed is still working in newer versions

Comment: so static broadcast receiver will work in this case?

Comment: yes static receivers work even when you are not using the same activity or the entire app

Comment: but how can I customise the static receiver according to my application logic, because in my android manifest file I have a pre-defined list of actions to choose from?

Comment: I am using API 30 and hence cannot use static receiver